# how to get path input from textbox and use in command button in vba macros

Tags: vba, path, textbox

I have textbox and command button in the form1.

I will input path in the textbox

After the clicking the command button, workbook from the path location should open and need to the require macros code like copying , etc

when i tried using the . I getting error saying that file1.xlsx not found . plz help

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("file1")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim file1 As String
file1 = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
```

Comment: for starters get rid of the `"` ... just write `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(file1)` Also, make sure your path is fully qualified with `\\server\folder\subfolder\filename`

Comment: Or more simply `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Value)` This way you can get rid of the entire `TextBox1_Change()`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You're right, but it's not enough to do that; the OP has to declare a module-level variable, and remove the local declaration.

Comment: @ZevSpitz sure . will do that .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestions in the comments above will get you where you need to go, but if I may suggest... rather than using a textbox for the user to enter the name in, use the GetOpenFilename dialog. In this way you can ensure that the path is valid and the file actually exists. It also gives the user a nice GUI which is more like what they're used to for a File -> Open dialog. Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim vnt As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    vnt = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm),*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm", 1, "Please select the file to open")

    If vnt = False Then Exit Sub

    Application.Workbooks.Open (vnt)

ExitPoint:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description

    Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot @alan k . for ur suggestion